# how to bold a text inside || || in latex?

Tags: latex

I have a problem bolding the text inside || || sign:
I tried to do this:

```
$\left\Vert \textbf{\lambda_{max}w} \right\Vert^{2}$
```

but I got || λ<sub>max</sub>w<sup>2</sup>.

However, I was able to do:

```
$\left\Vert \textbf{Aw} \right\Vert^2$
```

, which gives something like || **Aw** ||<sup>2</sup>. so I am not sure where I am wrong.

I want to make it looks like this || **λ<sub>max</sub>w** ||<sup>2</sup>, I just found out I can do this \textbf{w} to make w bold, but I cannot make λ<sub>max</sub> bold.

Probably a simple mistake, but I just cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Lambda is a math symbol, you will need a special package that modifies math symbols. In my case, I have used `\usepackage{bm}` and replaced `\textbf` with `\bm`. This made the results that you want it.

```
\documentclass{...}
    ...
    \usepackage{bm}
    ...
\begin{document}
    ...
    $\left\Vert \bm{ \lambda_{max}w } \right\Vert^2$
    ...
\end{document}
```

For more information, please visit [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols).